# Connection pool issues in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have encountered ResourceLimitException on Weblogic 10.3.6. While accessing application through 200 odd users, the ResourceLimitException comes up and my application goes down. 
I have checked the application code and did not find any connection leaks.Also, this issues comes up only when user load is huge.
Currently my current configuration is:
Maximum Capacity : 25
Initial Capacity : 1
Is this issues related to weblogic 10.3.6?

Comment: More info would be helpful, maybe the stacktrace?

Comment: com.compass.fw.business.exceptions.COMPRunTimeException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resources currently available in pool mwsAppDS to allocate to applications, please increase the size of the pool and retry..